# How to install a python egg

Tags: python, email, postfix-mta, egg

I'm trying to setup ftw.mail for my postfix installation.
Since I'm new to Linux and Python I don't really have a clue whether it is right, goes in the right direction or is rubbish.

From the official documentation I found this:

> - Add ftw.mail to your buildout configuration:
>    [instance]
>    eggs +=
>     ftw.mail
> - Install the generic setup import profile.

(source: https://github.com/4teamwork/ftw.mail/blob/master/README.rst)

My first question is: Would "/etc/postfix/" the so called "buildout configuration"?

Secondly I had struggles in how to build this "egg" I tried:

```
$ wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python for ez_setup
```

then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install python-setuptools
```

and to finish:

```
$ sudo easy_install ftw.mail
```

On the console I was told, that the egg was there:

> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ftw.mail-2.3.1-py2.7.egg

I found it and I've read that I had to start it with:

```
$ PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cssutils-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

which basically did nothing.
Now the question is: How do I install the egg?

To summarise my questions:

1. Is "etc/postfix/" the buildout configuration directory I'm looking for?
2. How do I install a Python egg?
3. And what am I supposed to do with:[instance] eggs += ftw.mail?
4. What is a "generic setup import profile"?

Comment: And no, `/etc/postfix` is not a Python configuration directory at all. It contains the configuration files for Postfix itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I did it by:

```
$ sudo easy_install /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/cssutils-1.0-py2.7.egg
```

Comment: thank you! i don't understand why "easy_install psycopg2" created an egg file but didn't actually install psycopg2